Opposite results using Bayesian (STAN) vs Multilevel model (nlme). How is this possible?
My datasets contains the median wages and the cumulative installed wind-capacity for 4000 counties over a period of 20 years. The wages tend to rise over the period and the capacity tends to highly differ between counties. As a first step I want to analyse the broad effect and later group counties by states and other categories.
I ran base level analysis in R using Bayesian Markov Chain Monte-Carlo (MCMC) simulation with STAN and got a small positive correlation which is also backed by other studies. The code must be correct as it is a near 100% replica of another study.
Now i tried to replicate the same using Hierarchical Linear Models using nlme and got a totally opposite result.
nmle:
model <- lme(median_wage ~ 
    cum_installed_wind + period, 
    random = ~ period | county_id,
    correlation = corAR1(
        form = ~ period | county_id),
        data = obs_level,
        method = "ML")

Stan:
data {
  int<lower = 0> N; // number of observations
  int<lower = 0> C; // number of counties
  int<lower = 1, upper=C> county[N]; // county ID
  vector[N] median_wage; // median yearly wages
  vector[N] period; // time period
  vector[N] capacity; // cumulative wind capacity
}

transformed data {
  vector[N] st_median_wage;
  vector[N] st_capacity;
  vector[N] st_period;

  // Standardize inputs
  st_median_wage = (median_wage - mean(median_wage)) / sd(median_wage);
  st_capacity = (capacity - mean(capacity)) / sd(capacity);
  st_period = (period - mean(period)) / sd(period);
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0> sigma_alphaW; // random intercept std dev
  real<lower=0> sigma_beta0W; // random slope std dev
  real<lower=0> sigma_y; // residual std dev

  real mu_alphaW; // mean of intercept
  real mu_beta0W; // mean of slope for period
  real beta1W; // fixed effect of wind capacity

  vector[C] alphaW_raw; // raw random intercepts
  vector[C] beta0W_raw; // raw random slopes for period
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[C] alphaW;
  vector[C] beta0W;
  vector[N] y_hat;

  // Compute random effects
  alphaW = mu_alphaW + sigma_alphaW * alphaW_raw;
  beta0W = mu_beta0W + sigma_beta0W * beta0W_raw;

  // Define the model prediction
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y_hat[i] = alphaW[county[i]] + beta0W[county[i]] * st_period[i] + beta1W * st_capacity[i];
  }
}

model {
  // Priors
  mu_alphaW ~ normal(0, 5);
  mu_beta0W ~ normal(0, 5);
  beta1W ~ normal(0, 5);
  sigma_alphaW ~ cauchy(0, 5);
  sigma_beta0W ~ cauchy(0, 5);
  sigma_y ~ cauchy(0, 5);

  alphaW_raw ~ normal(0, 1);
  beta0W_raw ~ normal(0, 1);

  // Likelihood
  median_wage ~ normal(y_hat, sigma_y);
}



Is this code correct for my analysis?
How are these opposite results possible?


I guess it would help people to answer if you give a bit more detail about the stan code and the results. Can you be more precise about "totally opposite results"? Does it mean strongly negative correlation? Also, if you plot the data, which result makes more sense to you? (NB: I'm not familiar with stan and not too familiar with lme)

Why is period a random effect? Why this error structure? Is that the same error structure as in the stan analysis?

What does "base level analysis" mean?

@PeterFlom I thought to use this to account for possibility that different counties experience different trends over time. The time period is 20 years and some counties just experience much greater growth than others.  I do account for this in STAN as well. I will add my STAN Code to the top. Thanks so much for helping so far!

@Roland I later want to group the counties by state and other characteristics. This is just the first analysis without any of the other parameters

@dariober Thank you! For the STAN i had a weak positive correlation inline with recent literature and for nmle a strong weak one.
